# There are 8 identical circles drawn on a sheet of paper. How many ways are there to do each of the following?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 8 identical circles drawn on a sheet of paper. How many ways are there to do each of the following?

a)exactly one in blue, exactly one in green, exactly one in red, and exactly one in yellow

b)Colour exactly 4 in purple

Not really sure where to start?

Comment: Hint on a) Start by choosing one  in order to give it a blue color (how many possibilities). Then go on with green, et cetera. Hint on b) turn each color into purple and notice that several original possibilities (how many?) give the same outcome.

Comment: I've done 8C4? is that correct?

Comment: For a) or for b)?

Comment: 8C4 as the answer for a

Comment: I reckon 8C4 stands for $\binom84$. Then it is not correct. There are $8\times7\times6\times5$ possibilities. See my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

a) You can look at this problem in two ways:

1. First choose four circles which will be colored, then assign the specific colors one by one. The number of ways to do this equals:

$${{8}\choose{4}} {{4}\choose{1}} {{3}\choose{1}} {{2}\choose{1}} {{1}\choose{1}} = \frac{8!}{4!\,4!} \cdot 4! = 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5= 1680$$

2. Choose one circle which will be colored blue, then one which will be colored green etc. The number of ways to do this equals:

$${{8}\choose{1}} {{7}\choose{1}} {{6}\choose{1}} {{8}\choose{1}} = 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5= 1680$$

b) In this case, we simply choose four circles which will be colored blue. The number of ways to do this thus equals:

$${{8}\choose{4}} = 70$$